# Removing the image from a UIbutton at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I want to remove a UIButton's image and replace it with a title at runtime. Although I am able to add the title to the UIButton, I am unable to remove the image. Does anyone have some advice?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like that?    `[myButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: I already tried this but not working. My code:   UIButton *btnLocation = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:1234554321];
   [btnLocation setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]; Although I am getting the new text on my button but it's not removing image.
   [btnLocation setTitle:[value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: The button is in a toolbar or navgationBar ?

Comment: It's a normal UIButton:    UIButton *btnLocation = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: ho have already an image in the button, where it's added ? in a xib ? or it's de default apparence ?

Comment: Receiving `Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier` log

Answer (score 6):

Your image must be the button's background image (otherwise you would not see your title text, the image property overrides the title property I believe).  So you must do:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:nil ...
```

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3 users

```
self.myButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swictch between two **different** images in 2 **different** buttons: (i.e. in nav bar)

[image]

```
final private func adaptUI(){
            if self.presentsFlag{
                let imgP = UIImage(named: "present_checked")
                let imgA = UIImage(named: "absent")
                self.presentBtn.image = imgP
                self.absentBtn.image = imgA
            }else{
                let imgP = UIImage(named: "present")
                let imgA = UIImage(named: "absent_checked")
                self.presentBtn.image = imgP
                self.absentBtn.image = imgA
            }
    }
```